# Why I get overlapped lines from a file when I read it in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, overlap

I'm trying to read a single file in Python and print it. I'm using this code for that:

```python
filename = 'test.txt'

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line
```

The content of the file ('test.txt'), is the next one:

```
MYPROGRAM
1   1   16/02/2015  2   4300004734  DOE, JOHN   201512  F/201512    132,00      1               DOE, JOHN   10180063X   ANY ADRESS Nº XX LEVEL DOOR 24397   CITY    STATE   COUNTRY                 2
1   2   16/02/2015  1   7000000000      201512  F/201512        120,00  1                                                           2
1   3   16/02/2015  3   4770000000      201512  F/201512        12,00   1   10,00                                       0   120,00          2
```

There are spaces, tabs and line breaks between the fields which are not being represented here.

The output is this weird thing:

```
1YPROGRA1       16/02/2015      2       4300004734      DOE, JOHN       201512  F/201512      1LEVEL D3OR     16/02/2015TY    3TATE   4770000000              201512  F/2015122             120,00
```

There are lines overlapping the other lines. Why? How can I solve this without modifying the original text file?

Comment: Can you please edit your post to correct file content?

Comment: It appears that 'test.txt' contains carriage returns `\r` but no newlines `\n`. Is it from a Mac? What OS and what version of Python are you using?

Comment: Are you sure that there are newlines? Can you confirm with something like: wc -l text.txt from your terminal?

Comment: The result of wc -l test.txt is 0 test.txt. My OS is Kubuntu 13.10 and the Python version is 2.7. The file comes from a Windows program. I edited the content of the file in this post, but I need someone again to put it right, like he did with the output earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file 'test.txt' contains carriage returns (`\r`) but no newlines (`\n`).

This code will read the whole file into a string, split it on carriage returns, then print it line by line:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    s = f.read()

for line in s.split('\r'):
    print line
```

Alternatively, you can split it and print it in one line:

```
print '\n'.join(s.split('\r'))
```

The second method is slightly more efficient, but the first one's a little more readable, IMHO.